# How do you enable GD in PHP when installing via RPM?

Tags: php, configuration, image, rpm, gd

We are working on a client's sever that has PHP running without GD. We would like to enable GD support in PHP on that machine. What is the most straightforward way to enable GD. Is there a way to do it via RPM?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Currently running:

RedHat Enterprise Linux Server version 5.3
Using RPM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in most modern packages this is done by installing the php-gd package with your package manager.

for RHEL 5.3 try:

```
yum install php5-gd
```

Comment: I am getting 
`Error: Package: gd-last-2.2.5-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libwebp.so.5()(64bit)`

Answer (score 3):

[root@a-sys1 ~]# **yum search "php" | grep -i gd**
php-gd.i386 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library

[root@a-sys1 ~]# **yum install php-gd**
Loading "dellsysidplugin2" plugin
etc etc

Comment: Good description of how to find the correct module.